# Can an empty Iterator be used to concat with another iterator in Java

Tags: java, iterator, guava, concatenation

I have an API which connects to DB and returns an Iterator. I have to call this API in loop to get records for multiple inputs. My requirement is to concatenate all iterators for which I am using `com.google.common.collect.Iterators` class.

My code snippet is shown below:

```
Iterator<Record> iterator = Iterators.emptyIterator();
for (QueryHolder<String> queryHolder : queries) {
    Iterators.concat(iterator, fetchAnotherRecordIterator(queryHolder));
}
return iterator;
```

But at the end I am getting empty iterator. On debugging, I am getting records from `fetchAnotherRecordIterator` method.

Don't know if we can append iterators to an empty iterator.

Comment: Have you tried it? Without ignoring the return value I mean.

Comment: Read the javadoc: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat-java.util.Iterator-java.util.Iterator-. **The returned iterator** iterates across the elements in a, followed by the elements in b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.google.common.collect.Iterators`is returning a new `Iterator` when you call the method `concat`. This means you have to update a reference with the new Iterator:

```
Iterator<Record> iterator = Iterators.emptyIterator();
for (QueryHolder<String> queryHolder : queries) {
    iterator = Iterators.concat(iterator, fetchAnotherRecordIterator(queryHolder));
}
return iterator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [`Iterators#concat(Iterator)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#concat-java.util.Iterator-) overload combined with [`Iterators#transform(Iterator, Function)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#transform-java.util.Iterator-com.google.common.base.Function-) (or corresponding functions from [`Iterables`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html)) for a one-liner:

```
return Iterators.concat(Iterators.transform(queries, this::fetchAnotherRecordIterator));
```

(Obviously gets dirty if you can't use Java 8 method references.)